# How do I count the number of different arrangements you get when flipping a coin 4 times?

Tags: probability

I am trying to count the number of elements in the set {HHHT,HHTH,HTHH,THHH,HHTT,HTHT,...} using either multiplication, permutation, or combination counting rules, but can't seem to conceptualize it. What method can I use to do this?

Comment: By induction. Start with one time. Then with two. ... Flipping a coin four times begins with flipping it three times.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using multiplication.  How many possibilities for the first flip?  How many for each of the others?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way of visualizing it is drawing a tree in my head.

[image]

You are moving from the root of the tree to it's leaves. On each vertex you have $2$ roads: either you go to the left or you go to the right. In order to decide where you should move next (*left* or *right*), you throw a coin.

If you see **heads**, you go to the *left*.
If you see **tails**, you go to the *right*.

[image]

All the paths from the root of the tree to it's leaves correspond to specific outcomes that might have happened to you, while you was throwing a coin.